# Does the number of involutions in an abelian group of order $2^n$ uniquely determine its isomorphism class?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

Saw an exam question quite a while ago on determining whether the statement:

> Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $2^n$. Suppose that $G$ has $m$ involutions. Then the isomorphism class of $G$ is uniquely determined.

is true. I was never able to solve it - I said that an element of $G$ must have order $2^i$ for some $i \le n$ by Lagrange's and that if $g$ is of order $2^i$ then $g^{2^{i - 1}}$ is an involution, and so there are only $m$ possible values for $g^{2^{i - 1}}$. I blagged that this meant that the orders of the elements are fixed by knowing the number of involutions - but this does not seem to use the abelian property anywhere.

There doesn't seem to be any counterexamples for $n = 2, 3, 4$. Is the statement true? If not, is this argument along the right lines?

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}_2\oplus\Bbb{Z}_8$ and $\Bbb{Z}_4\oplus \Bbb{Z}_4$? Generalize according to the hint in Hankry's answer.

Comment: Yes, so there is a counterexample for $n=4$. Why didn't you find it?

Comment: Ah, fair enough! Must have missed that one when checking $n = 4$, cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups should be useful here. We know that $G$ is a product of cyclic groups with even order. Then it comes down to does the number of involutions in $G$ determine invariant factors of $G$

Comment: I'm not familiar with these two terms, unfortunately. We did do the classification theorem but not that much more to that effect

Comment: Since $G$ has order a power of $2$, the elementary divisors and the invariant factors are identical. It's just powers of $2$, each dividing the next.

Comment: That’s true, I’ll edit out the elementary divisors part. Once you know that it’s a product of cyclic groups you can see that the total number of involutions is related to the number of factors in the decomposition. Then you can use Jyrki’s idea above. For any $n$ bigger than $2$ we can find non-isomorphic groups both having two invariant factors in their decomposition

Comment: You cannot for $n=3$. The only possibilities are $C_8$ (single involution), $C_2\times C_4$ with three; and $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$, with $7$. So for $n=3$, the number of involutions determines the isomorphism type.

Comment: That's true, I was wrong to say greater than 2, it should be greater than 3